# Http request using AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-http

I am trying to show the data coming from a server, 
I tried to make a controller and copy the response to a property of scope.
I tried 'response' and 'response.data' and none of them worked.

the html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Service Call ...</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("https://linkToServer.json")
                .success(function(response) {$scope.trainings = response.data;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">  
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="tr in trainings">
                {{ tr.id }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The json structure is something like:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "sm1001",
    "name" : "Lu",
  },
{
    "id" : "lm9898",
    "name" : "Di",
  },
  ....
]
```

What is wrong?

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/toSicojh58y1lWrziyI8?p=preview) of the problem

Comment: have you tried `.success(function(response) {$scope.trainings = response;` ?

Comment: @Vineet he already tried that..do read question carefully

Comment: The remote file is served over `https`. Is your script too?

Comment: I beg your pardon @PankajParkar I will keep it in mind for the next time.

Comment: Look at the network tab in your browser's debugger console, I bet you'll find an error there.

Answer (score 1):

Your plunk worked when I corrected the json. You did not include the json in the sample. I copied it from your question.

```
"name" : "Lu",
```

needs to be

```
"name" : "Lu"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/toSicojh58y1lWrziyI8?p=preview

This might be only your sample data. The angular code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your html is all messed up. First a `div`, then a `head` tag
I've updated your plunkr, now it's working: http://plnkr.co/edit/6Y1dX9vKkDANdZyEd0aj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed the order and still not working!